# How to make better smooth inner shadows for cards

Tags: html, css, shadow

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muxUE.png) is how I currently make inner shadows to cover text in cards. I create another div with a shadow and position it how I like in the card. It does not appear as smooth as other examples I see.

I have been toying with `box-shadow: inset...` but it comes out very messy.

I am going for something [Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsANM.jpg) from facebook. Very smooth inner shadow. Unfortunately, that card is for mobile only so I could not inspect its CSS.

Any advice to make nice, smoother shadows?

```css
.card {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  position: relative;

  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.card h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 75px;
}

.card .shadow {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 100px 100px rgba(0, 20, 245, 0.586);
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <h1>Some Text</h1>
  <div class="shadow"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried a linear-gradient over the background image instead of a shadow?

Comment: don't use `box-shadow` use`background-image` or `mask-image`